# Symfony 5, problem with doctrine for migration to database mariadb

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, mariadb, symfony5

I have a problem with symfony 5.

When I execute the command: `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`

I have an error:

> In MetadataStorageError.php line 13: The metadata storage is not up to
> date, please run the sync-metadata-storage command to fix this issue.

and I modify my `env.local` to specify the server version with MariaDB:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://db_user:.......@127.0.0.1:3306/bundletest?serverVersion=mariadb-10.5
```

and when I execute: `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`

I have another error:

> In DBALException.php line 86:
>
> ```
> Invalid platform version "mariadb-10.5" specified. The platform version has to be specified in the format:
> ```
>
> "^(?:5.5.5-)?(mariadb-)?<major_version>.<minor_version>.<patch_version>".

Comment: Did you try `?serverVersion=mariadb-10.5.0`? (the patch version _probably_ doesn't matter but you should still probably set that to your actual version

Comment: If that error message tells you the storage is not up to date, have you simply tried updating it (as the error message tells you)? Between `doctrine/migrations` v2 and v3, the table structure has changed

Answer (score 0):

Setting up doctrine migrations

same way to configure postgres and mysql (need to set different PDO driver of course, server version)|

**here is tested & working example up to symfony 5.2 & PHP 7.4**

you need two things to update in your project

1. after instaling doctrine you got new config file
   project_dir/config/packages/doctrine.yaml

please set is  as below

> ```
> doctrine:
> dbal:
>
>     driver: 'pdo_mysql'
>     server_version: '5.7'
>     charset: utf8mb4
>     default_table_options:
>         charset: utf8mb4
>         collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
>     url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
>
> orm:
>     auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
>     naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
>     auto_mapping: true
>     mappings:
>         App:
>             is_bundle: false
>             type: annotation
>             dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
>             prefix: 'App\Entity'
>             alias: App
> ```

and in your .env file

> #DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name"

uncoment, set your user and db settings, add ?serverVersion

> DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name?serverVersion=5.7

run

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create (it is better to create db with your project config settings)
```

and now you are free tu use migrations

Comment: this is fully tested working solution. Dont understand why someone downvoted this post...